# Get specific Content from Web page to Android

Tags: android, web, webview

I have a web site and there are some videos on it. 
I want to make Android app which doesn't load the whole web page, just the Video part. Is it possible? like loading youtube in WebView, but showing only video , not comments etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a video player in your app and based on the selected video load its URL to the video player and enable remote streaming to run the videos on the app. that should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have tired to run video in VideoView which is in .m3u8 format. but its not loading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562972/how-can-we-play-a-m3u8-file-in-android-2-2-or-android-2-3Not supported. is there any way to run .m3u8 in VideoView. Thanks

Comment: okay so this service is said to allow HTTP live streaming (M3U8), for Android 2.1+. this may turn out to be useful to you.
http://vov.io/vitamio/

Answer (score 1):

It is a best way to make one web service in your website that can give you whatever you need from your website (This will also can be use to make change on your web service and get more or less content from your own website)

To use this things you need to parse your page with **xml parser.**

I have done my project this way which display my website's videos in my android
My website link 
http://www.mycricketclips.com/.

I uses my android app to get all the displayed category and its video list in my android app.
and when I click on perticular video list, it will display that video on "webview" in android app.
Hope this might helpful for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. thats better apporoch. But unfortunately i am not able to make web service of website and format of video file is .m3u8

Comment: Can i check your web url of video in my Android app webView.?